# UITableViewCell layouts issue with autoresizing cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have tableview with custom dynamic autoresizing cell (UITableViewAutomaticDemension) Inside each cell I have collection view with images and resizing it according to content. above each collection view I have text label. sometimes text is blank. when you loading table view first time it's resizing collection view as needed and also taking layouts of label and resizing it as well. so I getting blank label with some height that is should't be. It's disappearing after I scroll tableview. What could be the issue? Do I need some manipulations with auto layouts also? Please advice

[image]

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280318/ios-8-uitableview-first-row-has-wrong-height

Comment: @crizzis Thanks according these answer now it seems better. Thanks